# Save shapefile as mat file using python?

Tags: python, scipy, fiona

After reading a shapefile using the following:
Using Fiona

```
y_data = fiona.open("example.shp")
y_data.schema
```

and I came across how to save it as a mat file by doing:

```
scipy.io.savemat("example_save.mat", y_data)
```

The following error showed up:
**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with geopandas, and it seems to work. Check this out.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from scipy.io import loadmat


# LOAD shapefile using gpd
gdf=gpd.read_file(r"path\to_your_data.shp")


#SAVE the data
scipy.io.savemat("path\to_your_data.mat", gdf)


# LOAD .mat file
y_data = loadmat('path\to_your_data.mat')
```